# Node.js CSV-parser - columns false -> group several arrays into one object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Firstly, I use the CSV-parser from Node.js

first this code:

```
const parse = require("csv-parse/lib/sync");
const fs = require("fs");

const filePath = req.file.path;

const csvContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

const records = parse(csvContent, {
        columns: false,
        skip_empty_lines: true,
        skip_lines_with_error: true,
        delimiter: ";"
    });
```

Now I have the problem that equal columns names will not be parsed if column are true.. if columns are true the results in the console are:

```
const records = parse(csvContent, {
        columns: true,


[ { Referenz: 'Beispielwert1',
    Client: 'Beispielwert2',
    Clienthauptgruppe: 'Beispielwert3',
    Kontrahent: 'Beispielwert4',
    Kontrahentenhauptgruppe: 'Beispielwert5',
    Bank: 'Beispielwert6',
    Back_to_Back: 'Beispielwert7',
    Int_Ext: 'Beispielwert8',
    Valuta: 'Beispielwert9',
    Geschaeftsart: 'Beispielwert10',
    Kauf_Verkauf: 'Beispielwert11',
    Wrg: 'Beispielwert12',
    Diff_In_Hauswaehrung: 'Beispielwert13,
    Hauswaehrung: 'Beispielwert14',
    Marktwert_NPV: 'Beispielwert5' },
  { Referenz: 'Beispielwert1',
    Client: 'Beispielwert2',
    Clienthauptgruppe: 'Beispielwert3',
    Kontrahent: 'Beispielwert4',
    Kontrahentenhauptgruppe: 'Beispielwert5',
    Bank: 'Beispielwert6',
    Back_to_Back: 'Beispielwert7',
    Int_Ext: 'Beispielwert8',
    Valuta: 'Beispielwert9',
    Geschaeftsart: 'Beispielwert10',
    Kauf_Verkauf: 'Beispielwert11',
    Wrg: 'Beispielwert12',
    Diff_In_Hauswaehrung: 'Beispielwert13,
    Hauswaehrung: 'Beispielwert14',
    Marktwert_NPV: 'Beispielwert5' }]
```

if columns are false the results in the console are:

```
const records = parse(csvContent, {
        columns: false,

[ [ 'Referenz',
    'Client',
    'Clienthauptgruppe',
    'Kontrahent',
    'Kontrahentenhauptgruppe',
    'Bank',
    'Back_to_Back',
    'Int_Ext',
    'Valuta',
    'Geschaeftsart',
    'Kauf_Verkauf',
    'Wrg',
    'Diff_In_Hauswaehrung',
    'Hauswaehrung',
    'Marktwert_NPV' 
    'Wrg'],
  [ 'Beispielwert1',
    'Beispielwert2',
    'Beispielwert3',
    'Beispielwert4',
    'Beispielwert5',
    'Beispielwert6',
    'Beispielwert7',
    'Beispielwert8',
    'Beispielwert9',
    'Beispielwert10',
    'Beispielwert11',
    'Beispielwert12',
    'Beispielwert13',
    'Beispielwert14',
    'Beispielwert15'
    'Beispielwert16' ],
  [ 'Beispielwert1',
    'Beispielwert2',
    'Beispielwert3',
    'Beispielwert4',
    'Beispielwert5',
    'Beispielwert6',
    'Beispielwert7',
    'Beispielwert8',
    'Beispielwert9',
    'Beispielwert10',
    'Beispielwert11',
    'Beispielwert12',
    'Beispielwert13',
    'Beispielwert14',
    'Beispielwert15'
    'Beispielwert16' ]]
```

Here for example the column Wrg is the double column and if columns stands on: true.. it doesn't exist

Now I want the same form again as above mentioned if columns are true.. but how can I put multiple Arrays to one object if the multiple arrays are in one variable (records)?

Best regards

Frederic

Comment: I'd suggest adding your required result to your question, is this something like: { 'Referenz': ['Beispielwert1','Beispielwert1','Beispielwert1'], 'Client': ['Beispielwert2','Beispielwert2','Beispielwert2'] ... thanks!

Comment: my required result is the result that i get if the columns is 'true' but then for example the double column Wrg doesn't exist.. Therefore I need the same structure but now with the double column.. and i think one can not avoid the rebuilding because only if the columns is 'false' the double column exist.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you.. I understand now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remap each row value, updating any duplicate fields with a unique number.. that will then change 'Wrg' to 'Wrg2' for example. You can also map to a single column, with an array of the fields present instead, I've included both approaches below:

```
const parse = require("csv-parse/lib/sync");
const fs = require("fs");

const filePath = req.file.path;
const csvContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

let records = parse(csvContent, {
    delimiter: ";",
    skip_empty_lines: true,
    skip_lines_with_error: true,
});

function getFieldNameArray(row) {
    return row.reduce((fieldNames, originalFieldName) => {
        let fieldName = originalFieldName;
        let uniqifier = 1;
        while (fieldNames.includes(fieldName)) {
            fieldName = `${originalFieldName}${++uniqifier}`; // You could use a different algorithm for this purpose.. e.g. use field_duplicate etc.. 
        }
        fieldNames.push(fieldName);
        return fieldNames;
    }, []);
}

const fieldNames = getFieldNameArray(records[0]);

records = records.slice(1).map((currentRow, index) => {
    return currentRow.reduce((prev, value, index) => {
        prev[fieldNames[index]] = value;
        return prev;
    }, {});
}, records)

console.log(records);
```

I get an output like so:

```
[ { Referenz: 'Beispielwert1',
    Client: 'Beispielwert2',
    Clienthauptgruppe: 'Beispielwert3',
    Kontrahent: 'Beispielwert4',
    Kontrahentenhauptgruppe: 'Beispielwert5',
    Bank: 'Beispielwert6',
    Back_to_Back: 'Beispielwert7',
    Int_Ext: 'Beispielwert8',
    Valuta: 'Beispielwert9',
    Geschaeftsart: 'Beispielwert10',
    Kauf_Verkauf: 'Beispielwert11',
    Wrg: 'Beispielwert12',
    Diff_In_Hauswaehrung: 'Beispielwert13',
    Hauswaehrung: 'Beispielwert14',
    Marktwert_NPV: 'Beispielwert15',
    Wrg2: 'Beispielwert16' }
]
```

If you wish to create an array of values under 'Wrg', this should work:

```
const parse = require("csv-parse/lib/sync");
const fs = require("fs");

const filePath = req.file.path;
const csvContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

let records = parse(csvContent, {
    delimiter: ";",
    skip_empty_lines: true,
    skip_lines_with_error: true,
});

let fieldNames = Object.values(records[0]);

records = records.slice(1).map((currentRow) => {
    return currentRow.reduce((prev, value, index) => {
        if (!prev.hasOwnProperty(fieldNames[index])) {
            prev[fieldNames[index]] = value;
        } else {
            let existing = prev[fieldNames[index]];
            prev[fieldNames[index]] = (Array.isArray(existing) ? existing: [existing]).concat(value);
        }
        return prev;
    }, {});
})


console.log(records);
```

I get an output like so:

```
[ { Referenz: 'Beispielwert1',
    Client: 'Beispielwert2',
    Clienthauptgruppe: 'Beispielwert3',
    Kontrahent: 'Beispielwert4',
    Kontrahentenhauptgruppe: 'Beispielwert5',
    Bank: 'Beispielwert6',
    Back_to_Back: 'Beispielwert7',
    Int_Ext: 'Beispielwert8',
    Valuta: 'Beispielwert9',
    Geschaeftsart: 'Beispielwert10',
    Kauf_Verkauf: 'Beispielwert11',
    Wrg: [ 'Beispielwert12', 'Beispielwert16' ],
    Diff_In_Hauswaehrung: 'Beispielwert13',
    Hauswaehrung: 'Beispielwert14',
    Marktwert_NPV: 'Beispielwert15' },
]
```

Comment: thanks! what do you mean with duplicate? I think with 'duplicate! the problem will occur again because the column name is equal

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right.. the other approaches will work very well in any case!